# Geodjango render_to_kml Multipolygons - Can be fast or faster as WMS?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml, geodjango, rendering

I am learning now geodjango. I made basic web app with postgis database. With openlayers  iam displaying basic wms map and I want to add other layers from my postgis database. I use render_to_kml function and then I visualize this kml with openlayers. The problem is that I can only display point layers instead of multipolygons...I tried to make another kml template bud I misunderstand it and there is no good documentation... I paste here my files ( view, template, urls) and please give me advice if you can,,,where I have mistake ( I think it will be something with KML templates but i dont know.)

[image: this is my views.py]

[image: this is my html template]

1. this is my views.py
2. this is my html template
3. this is my urls.py
   [image: this is my urls.py]

This results into application with 3 layers (basic map and 2layers from my postgis database which are equivalent (both are point feature....Polygons feature is only copy of Point feature...Thats my problem))...
Anyone has a solution for me?

Comment: Are the coordinates for the polygon data being parsed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I made another kml template and also made a copy of base.kml template in same directory and saved as base2.kml... then rewrite my polygons.kml to be in base2.kml and it works for me, i displayed both layers, but KML it is very slow , and i am thinking about geoserver and publish it from postgis database as WMS, it would be faster and i put there funkcionality that poeple can download KML format if they want.....or anyone have better solution for faster rendering?